# How to change underline length in TextInputLayout and make it to start with text position?

Tags: android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I use TextInputLayout in my Profile screen

[Profile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY50z.jpg)

and I want to underline, text, and floating hint were align. But underline wider and I can't find easy way to line them up.

my xml:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/nameField"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="@string/PROFILE_NAME_HINT"
        android:inputType="text" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Version of material in gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
```

I tried to change styles, paddings, it doesn't help. I've noticed that old version of material in other expamples show needed result.

Answer (score 1):

On the `TextInputEditText` set `paddingStart` to `0dp`.

```
android:paddingStart="0dp"
```